# Force Setup of SMS 2FA Mobile Number During Custom Registration Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible through the means of a custom policy, if you already have a mobile number for a user, to setup SMS 2FA in Azure AD B2C for a user when they are being registered/signed-up?  I.e. without presenting them a UI where they enter their mobile, but instead a means of setting their 2FA mobile number for them?  We are imagining we can retrieve the user's mobile number, mid-flow, by means of an API call.

We haven't discovered anything yet to suggest we can set a SMS 2FA mobile number during registration.  Can anyone suggest a way forward?

Note: as an extra bonus we aren't permitted to use the Microsoft Graph Beta API.

Comment: I've been working... no, been trying to work with Azure AD B2C for the past 6 months and I'm pretty sure that the answer is unfortunately no. Without being able to use the Graph API, your chances are even more slim. As far as I know, it's designed like so that it pretty much wants to force the 2FA "properly" by asking everyone their number when the policy is enabled and sending them the verification code. We haven't found any place to put the phone numbers in ahead of time so it wouldn't do that, even with Graph API.

Comment: You should be able to write it to an extension attribute with v1 ms graph api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not proofing up so you need to be sure that you have the correct number.

This TP - "AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" writes the phone number:

```
<PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
</PersistedClaims>
```

which may work?

Not sure if proofing up writes some extra attributes in the background? e.g.

"PhoneFactor-Verify".

**Update**

wrt to the comment, you [can](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/proofing-up-users-programmatically-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-either-email-or-phone-71a71f579235).

Comment: Many thanks, we just tried this and I can confirm that it writes the phone number straight into the correct place.